# I tried to add a function that takes new usernames and passwords to my dictionary but It doesn't recognize the new info

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have just started to learn Python and I tried to write a code that asks for your username and password, this part is working well. Also, I tried to add a function (**function2**) that takes new usernames and passwords to my dictionary (**users**) but unfortunately, It doesn't recognize the new user. How can I correct my code?

```
users = {"admin": "123456"}

def function2():
    for x, y in users.items():
        username = input('Enter a new username: ')
        if x == username:
            print('Username: \"' + username + '\" is in use.')
            return function2()
    password = input('Choose a password: ')
    users[username] = password
    print('You may now login.')
    return function4()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Commendations for jumping into the adventure of learning programming with Python.

That said, your code has several bad design decisions that make it hard to see the actual problem:

- Your function names are very generic. This makes the program hard to read and will become worse as your programs grow. Choosing meaning full names, e.g. `login`, `add_user` etc. will reduce mental load and help focus on the problem at hand.
- Your code jumps between functions by calling them as `return` values. This (a) makes it hard to understand the execution path, and (b) slowly fills up the call stack, needlessly consuming memory and eventually leading to a stack overflow (no pun intended).

Concerning your login problem:
Entering a new user to the `users` list works fine. However, consider what happens when checking the list of users in `function1`:

- Assume you added another user, so `users = {"admin": "123456", "user2":"pass2"}`.
- You want to login as `user2`, so `username="user2"` and `password="pass2"`.
- The first entry of `users` is checked, setting `x="admin"` and `y="123456"`.
- clearly, `username==x` is wrong, so both `if` branches will be skipped.
- you land in the `else` branch.

Instead, get rid of the `for` loop and check like this:

```
if username in users:
    if users[username] == password:
        print("Login successful")
        return True
    else:
        print("Wrong password")
        return False
else:
    print("User does not exist")
```

Answer (score 1):

When starting off a code like this in python a function and for loop may not be required. Using "in" will work here. Note: .keys() is similar to the .items() you were using.

Once that is running and you code gets more complicated the functions and loops can be added.

```
users = {"admin": "123456"}

username = input('Enter a new username: ')
if username in users.keys():
    print('Username: \"' + username + '\" is in use.')
else:
    password = input('Choose a password: ')
    users[username] = password
    print('You may now login.')

# Print command to check the results
print(users)

You may now login.
{'admin': '123456', 'Frog': '456'}
```

For the dictionary updates I have added some code below as a simplified example of function2(). I have stripped out the inputs and put in placeholder variables to simplify them. Once the function are working properly the complexity can be added back in.

```
# Modified function2()
def function2():
    username = 'sample str 2'
    if username in users:
        print('Username: \"' + username + '\" is in use.')
    else:
        password = 543
        users[username] = password
        print('You may now login.')
    #return function4()

# Example dictionary
users = {'sample str': 212, 'sample str 1': 421}

print(users)
```

{'sample str': 212, 'sample str 1': 421}

```
# Run function
function2()
```

You may now login.

```
# Results - dictionary is updated
print(users)
```

{'sample str': 212, 'sample str 1': 421, 'sample str 2': 543}

When you move into running all the functions together I recommend using a loop (for, while, ...) to call the functions rather than looping the function calls and returns. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your suggestion made my code more effective but the problem remains. My function can't modify the dictionary. Maybe there is an error somewhere else, I am sharing full code.

Answer (score 0):

```
users = {"admin": "123456"}


def function1():
    print('Enter your information please')
    username = input('Username: ')
    password = input('Password: ')
    for x, y in users.items():
        if username == x and password == y:
            print('Login successful')
        elif username == x:
            print('Password is wrong')
            return function4()
        else:
            print('Username doesn\'t exist')
            return function4()


def function2():
    username = input('Enter a new username: ')
    if username in users.keys():
        print('Username: \"' + username + '\" is in use.')
    else:
        password = input('Choose a password: ')
        users[username] = password
        print('You may now login.')
    return function4()


def function3():
    print('Invalid entry')
    return function4()


def function4():
    x = input('Login, Join or Exit?')
    if x == 'Login':
        function1()
    elif x == 'Join':
        function2()
    elif x == 'Exit':
        return 0
    else:
        function3()


function4()
```